# Constraints are not applied when moving all four of them to themes.XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-theme

I have a ConstraintLayout in which I have placed a ProgressBar right in the center.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/ProgressBarStyle"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

All four constraints are located themes.XML file in ProgressBarStyle:

```
<style name="ProgressBarStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintStart_toStartOf">parent</item>
    <item name="layout_constraintTop_toTopOf">parent</item>
</style>
```

Even if the ProgressBar is displayed in the center in Android Studio, see the image below:

[image]

I get the following warning:

> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints

So even if the constraints are present in the themes.XML file, I still get this warning. How to solve this?

Comment: What is happening on an emulator?

Comment: @Marat Also in the emulator is placed in center, not only in Android Studio. But why is this error? The constraints are already present.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can not set constraints for view within style.constraints should be under constraint layout.when you write xml code, layout try to find all constraints to place the view in preview window.they won't look at style for constraints.that's why you got warning.to avoid warning move all four constraints from style to layout.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any official documentation for that? And why do other properties work properly and only the constrains not? And why is in Android Studio looking good, as well in the emulator?

Comment: No ,i don't see anything in documentation .but  i  got same pbm when i try to write reusable code in style .As i said it will  show only warning  ,at run time style will work.@joan P

Comment: So can I keep it that way and only suppress the warning? Or will I get in trouble?

Comment: I think it's better to move to layout.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just up-voted your answer. I hope I'll also get other answers.

Comment: Am also following your question to know about it!@JoanP.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this in the past - just looks like an case that is not handled when checking the constraints. You are not doing anything wrong.

`tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` will get rid of the error. You can apply this to each view that displays the error or in the *ConstraintLayout* XML so it will apply to the entire layout.